# Is there a way to make a param optional in PHP PDO?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Say I have this query:

```
$qry = 'SELECT p.id FROM products p 
        WHERE p.type = :type AND p.parent = :parent';
```

If I wanted to make "type" optional then the only way I know how to do it would be to do something like this:

```
$qry = 'SELECT p.id FROM products p 
        WHERE p.parent = :parent';

if(isset($type))
{
    $qry .= 'AND p.type = :type';
}
```

Is this the best way? I am wondering if there is a way I can keep it like the original, and use some sort of parameter to indicate that it is optional... For example if $type = "*" then pull all types.

Whats the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check for blank values as well

```
if(isset($type) && $type != '') {
    $qry .= 'AND p.type = :type';
}
```

Comment: or simply `if(!empty($type)) {}`

Comment: It depends if a blank value if a valid value for the field does it not?

Comment: @choise I like != '' as empty() sees 0 (int/string) and FALSE as empty but they could be acceptable values.

Comment: @nev stokes, agreed but I would also agree if your looking for a set value that it wouldn't be blank. 2 cents

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically this might work:

```
 AND :type IN (NULL, p.type)
```

Not sure about the speediness. But it puts your query logic completely into the database.